# Getting datetime from binary

Tags: python, datetime, binary

I want to get a date and time in the form of 1/1/2000. The program I am making reads from a compressed document that stores a table of information. The program gets to a date time cell and pulls out

- 946652400 as a int
- or 11110000110001000110110000111000 as binary

This should be interpreted as Fri Dec 31 15:00:00 UTC 1999 which I want it to display as 1/1/2000. Is there a method of some form in python that I can use? I can also display this information as 12/31/1999 as well. If not can someone explain how to create this from the example above?

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using datetime:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(946652400)
datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 1, 0, 0)
```

Timezones are a mess, especially if you have to worry about the future.
But if you're just dealing with the past, you can always apply a static offset to adjust the value to the desired timezone.

The value you have given is already in 1/1/2000, you can adjust it back to UTC if you know the appropriate offset.

```
>>> dt = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(946652400)
>>> OFFSET = datetime.timedelta(hours=-9)
>>> adjusted_dt = dt + OFFSET
datetime.datetime(1999, 12, 31, 15, 0)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
import time
time_struct = time.gmtime(946652400)
print time.strftime('%d/%m/%Y', time_struct)
```

The time module is part of the stdlib: documented [here](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html)
And here's a [table](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.strftime) showing the `%m` format directives you can use in `strftime`.